# Need to check username and email do exist before storing data on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
User.find({username : username}, function (err, docs){
    if (docs.length){
         console.log(docs.length);
    }else{
         console.log('Insert');
    }
});
```

Now i am able to check username but not on both. My Query is either username or email if exist then show message that username is exist or email is exist..
i have a working function for storing the data to db

Comment: What you want ?

Comment: You achieve it using Mongoose Schema.validate method to do so.

Answer (score 3):

```
User.find({$or: [{email: email},{username: username}]}, function (err, docs) {
            if (docs.length!=0){
                //console.log(req.body.email);
                // Check record has same username as you are using in find
                if(docs[0].username == username){
                    //console.log(docs[0].email);
                    //console.log(docs[0].username);
                    //console.log(docs[0].username+'__'+username);
                    console.log("username Already exist");
                }
                // Else Check record has same email as you are using in find
                else if(docs[0].email == email){
                    console.log("Email Already exist");
                }
            }else{
                console.log('Insert');
            }

});
```

There is only one problem that on both cases it returns on the first condition that is "Username already taken."

Comment: You have to check `docs[0].username == username` and `docs[0].email == email`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$or` operator.

```
  User.find({$or: [
        {email: req.body.email},
        {username: req.body.username}
    ]}, function(err, docs) {
        //do anything
        //if(email) is matched{ console.log("Email already taken ");}
        //else if(username) is matched{ console.log("Username already taken")}
        else{
            //call Update function
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Sreerag A R for this.

Comment: If I want to show specific message then how it be.. Like for this query it simple return my console handy message. Now I want if username exist and email not exist then on message will be "Username had already taken". just stuck with this query.

Comment: @Abhay
`if(docs.email === req.body.email) console.log("email already taken")
else console.log("username already taken")`

Answer (score 0):

For Mongoose version 7 onwards you cant use callbacks, therefore one solution is to use .then() method like so:

```
User.find({ $or: [{ username: req.body.username },{ email: req.body.email} ],}).then(result) => {
//since the result is an array of objects you should get the first element of it in order to have access to the username/email property
//to prevent any errors if there is no users found make sure to use the optional chaining operator '?.'
  if(result[0]?.username === username) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: "Username is already in use!"}) 
  } else if {result[0]?.email === email) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: "Email is already in use!"}) 
  } 
}
```